# Oracle Analytic Preceding Returns wrong/unanticipated results

Tags: sql, oracle, date, analytics

Writing a SQL query that should return the average charges for a preceding 91 day window. I truncate the date down to the first day of the week and expect the 91 day average to be the 91 days **prior** to this date.

However when validating it appears that the 91 day average is including the current week that I truncated.

Query:

```
SELECT
    week AS WEEK,
    to_char(week,'ww-yyyy') AS Week_num
    --Sum of the charges for the previous 91 days / 91 will give you avg charges per day for the last 91 days
    --Need to count days regardless of if there are any charges on that day
    ,(SUM(CHARGES) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK RANGE INTERVAL '91' DAY PRECEDING))/91 MV_91_DAY_AVG
FROM 
( 

    SELECT
         --Truncate date down to first of week. Goal is to make 91 day preceding being at this date.
         TRUNC(TRANS.ORIG_POST_DATE,'WW') AS WEEK
         ,SUM(TRANS.AMOUNT) AS CHARGES
    FROM TRANS
    WHERE
        TRANS.DETAIL = "Charge"
    GROUP BY TRUNC(TRANS.ORIG_POST_DATE,'WW')
)
ORDER BY WEEK
```

Current output:
[image]

Comment: If you have a question similar to mine above I highly encourage you to check out this overview of Oracle Analytic functions that can be found on youtube at sheepsqueezers channel, http://www.youtube.com/user/sheepsqueezersYT/search?query=analytic,  or http://www.sheepsqueezers.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want your window clause to be:

```
(ORDER BY WEEK RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '91' DAY PRECEDING AND INTERVAL '1' DAY PRECEDING)
```

in order to exclude the current week's charges.

You may also want to change the '91' to '92' to include an additional week at the beginning.

Comment: Brilliant this did the trick. So I have to admit I still don't understand why my query was grabbing the current week and what makes yours exclude it. If you have a minute to explain that would be great. Or feel free to point me to some documentation I should review. I'm just not quiet sure where to look. Either way... many thanks!

Comment: @Cimplicity: You were just giving the start point of a range to include.  The default end point is the current row, and it is inclusive.  By explicitly setting an endpoint of `INTERVAL `1` DAY PRECEDING`, the current row is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the current value before dividing?

```
,(SUM(CHARGES) OVER (ORDER BY WEEK RANGE INTERVAL '91' DAY PRECEDING) - CHARGES)/91
```

Comment: I gave this a try but no dice. It changes the numbers completely. Right now the numbers are correct just offset by a week. Thanks for the suggestion though... ;)